# How do I subtract a number with an if-statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my code:

```
import sys
import click


def Seats():
    global seats
    seats = 168
    print("\nThe current seating capacity is {}\n".format(seats))


def Restart():
    while True:
        restart = click.confirm('\nWould you like to subtract 1 from seats?',
                                default=True)

        if restart == True:
            x = seats - 1
            Seats()
        elif restart == False:
            print("\nOk, see you next time!\n")
            sys.exit()


Seats()
Restart()
```

I want to ask the user "Would you like to subtract 1 from seats?" and then subtract one from seats variable and then repeat until the users inputs `no`.

Comment: seats is reset to 168 each time you run `Seats()`.  Also, `x = seats - 1` does not change the value of seats at all...

Comment: Sidenote: Usually, `if x == True: ... elif x == False:` can be simplified to `if x: ... else:`. But I've never used `click` so IDK if `click.confirm()` might return another value.

Comment: Another sidenote: no need to `sys.exit()` when you could just `return`

Comment: You said "and then repeat until the users inputs `n`", what is `n`?

Comment: @martineau I'm pretty sure that means the actual letter `n`, as in "no".

Comment: OP: if you have problems at this conceptual level, you should probably try to work all the way through someone else's tutorial first before trying to work out code for your own projects.

Comment: Thanks @Karl, that seems obvious now — don't know what I was thinking (other than I'm not familiar with what `click` does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, the main problem in your code is here:

```
def Seats():
    global seats
    seats = 168
    print("\nThe current seating capacity is {}\n".format(seats))
```

Whenever and wherever you call the function `Seats` in your code, the value of `seats` is redefined because `seats = 168` gets executed.

With the problem pointed out, I tried to edit your code maintaining the same structure in order to try to show you how to fix the problem, but changed my mind. The code, despite small, has an unnecessarily complex logic and a far from clean syntax. You are a beginner, so there is no problem with that! It is just that, because of that, I thought that showing you another way to implement this algorithm would be more valuable. Here it goes:

```
import click


seats = 168
while seats > 0:
    subtract_seat = click.confirm('\nWould you like to subtract 1 from seats?', default = True)
    if subtract_seat:
        seats -= 1
        print("\nThe current seating capacity is {}\n".format(seats))
    else:
        break
print("\nOk, see you next time!\n")
```

1. Do not need to import the `sys` library. You are not using it
2. `while seats > 0` avoids subtracting seats when there are no more seats left and is also the main loop used to interact with the user
3. The `else` clause will automatically take care if the first condition is not met
4. There is absolutely no need for functions or global variables in your code. They might be needed if you insert this code in a bigger context, but keep simplicity in mind

#AshidoBestGirl

Comment: Ahh yess! Thank you so much. This is very very useful I appreciate the help. Also thanks for the explanation it is very valuable

Answer (score 0):

To get things to work you have to declare `seats` to be a global variable in the `Restart()` function and stop resetting it in the `Seats()` function. It doesn't have to be declared in the version of the `Seats()` function below because it no longer tries to set or change its value.

To subtract a number from a variable and store the result back into the variable, you need to either do `variable = variable - number` **or** use the more succinct `variable -= number` statement.

Also, when you want to terminate the while loop in `Restart()` and let it "fall of the end" and `return`, all you need to do is `break` out of the `while True` loop.

Here's your code with those changes:

```
import click


seats = 168  # Initialize global variable.

def Seats():
    print("\nThe current seating capacity is {}\n".format(seats))

def Restart():
    global seats

    while True:
        restart = click.confirm('\nWould you like to subtract 1 from seats?',
                                default=True)

        if restart:
            seats -= 1
            Seats()
        else:
            print("\nOk, see you next time!\n")
            break


Seats()
Restart()
```